# Determine one-sided limits of a function given its graph (no analytical formula)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

I need some help figuring this out.

[image]

So this time I have a problem which requires us to determine some of the one-sided limits based on the graph.

I deduced the values for some of the limits (whereas I'm not entirely sure for the last one), and for the others I don't even know where to start. Here are the ones I could find a value for:

$$\lim_{x \to -1-} f(x) = 1$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x) = -\infty$$
$$\lim_{x \to -2-} f(x) = 2$$

I am not sure about the last one, because if we are approaching $x$ from both sides we end up at $(-2,2)$ but the function is defined for $x=-2$ by $y=1$ so I am not sure.

Now here are the ones I couldn't find (to be quite frank I don't even understand them):

$$\lim_{x \to 1-} ((x-1)^2f(x) $$
$$\lim_{x \to 2+} (f(x)f(-x)) $$

1. Could anyone clarify what happens when x approaches $-2^-$ and why?
2. Could anyone explain the two limits I have not been able to comprehend?

Keep in mind that we have not yet covered the subject of derivatives and continuity (although I am familiar with it).

Thanks!

Comment: @ombk my understanding is that a sided limit is the value y approaches as we approach x from left or right

Comment: please let me know if my explanation is clear to continue helping you solve the last 2 questions

Comment: @ombk Very clear! Thanks!

Comment: plz if possible post your answers for the 2 questions, so I can assure that u are able to solve them

Comment: @ombk Sorry, do you mean the two limits I have not been able to solve? 

For the first one, I tried plugging in the value $1^-$ and ended up with  $\lim{x \to1^-} (0^-f(x))$ but I have no idea what to do next, this doesn't yield anything. I don't know what it graphically represents. 

The second one well as I see it it's a product of $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ but I don't see it going anywhere? Sorry

Comment: will help and develop my answer

Answer (score 1):

***Explanation***

So sided limits are a bit tricky, you have to always remember that there is two ways of seeing a number or approaching it, from the left (or coming from $- \infty$ or from the right coming from $+\infty$.

Therefore,

*Could anyone clarify what happens when x approaches $−2^−$ and why?*

Now we are approaching the value $-2$ from the $-$ side which is $- \infty$ , therefore you can imagine that $-2^-$ is something close to $-2.0000000000001$ .

On the other hand if we were approaching $-2$ from the $+$ side, we would be coming from $+ \infty$ which yields something close to $-1.9999999999$.

Now the trick in this particular exercise, is that on $-2$ there's one hell of a mess, but i will make it easier for you.

Coming from the left or right side of $-2$, we have a discontinuity as you can see. And $EXACTLY$ on $x=-2$ we have the black dot which is a value and not a limit for $f$.

In other words $lim -2^{-+} f(x) = 2$ and $f(-2)=1$

***Help for the last 2 parts***

As you were able to find $(x-1)f(x)$ yields a $0*f(x)$ and since $f(1^-)=1$. Therefore, we end up having a 0.